# Function append lines to .csv

Tags: python, function, text-files

It has been awhile since I have written functions with for loops and writing to files so bare with my ignorance.

This function is given an IP address to read from a text file; pings the IP, searches for the received packets and then appends it to a .csv

My question is: Is there a better or an easier way to write this?

```
def pingS (IPadd4):
   fTmp = "tmp"
   os.system ("ping " + IPadd4 + "-n 500 >  tmp")
   sName = siteNF #sys.argv[1]
   scrap = open(fTmp,"r")   
   nF = file(sName,"a") # appends
   nF.write(IPadd4 + ",")

   for line in scrap:
    if line.startswith("    Packets"):
        arrT = line.split(" ")  
        nF.write(arrT[10]+" \n")
   scrap.close()
   nF.close()
```

*Note: If you need the full script I can supply that as well.*

Answer (score 1):

This in my opinion at least makes what is going on a bit more obvious. The len('Received = ') could obviously be replaced by a constant.

```
def pingS (IPadd4):    
    fTmp = "tmp"    
    os.system ("ping " + IPadd4 + "-n 500 >  tmp")    
    sName = siteNF #sys.argv[1]    
    scrap = open(fTmp,"r")       
    nF = file(sName,"a") # appends 

    ip_string = scrap.read()
    recvd = ip_string[ip_string.find('Received = ') + len('Received = ')]
    nF.write(IPadd4 + ',' + recvd + '\n')
```

You could also try looking at the [Python `csv` module](http://www.python.org/doc/current/library/csv.html) for writing to the csv. In this case it's pretty trivial though.

Comment: I test your code it and doesn't work, it returns an's' instead of value of received packets.

Comment: That errors in your original code too then, - it comes about because there is not space before the '-n' in 'os.system ("ping " + IPadd4 + "-n 500 >  tmp")'. 

Put a space before the '-n' and the code should work fine (I've tested it).

I was assuming your input IP addresses had a space after them.

Comment: My apologies, I just re-tested with the updated space and now it partially works. If I ping lets say -n 10. The .csv is only recording a 1. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

This may not be a direct answer, but you may get some performance increase from using StringIO. I have had some dramatic speedups in IO with this. I'm a bioinformatics guy, so I spend a lot of time shooting large text files out of my code.

http://www.skymind.com/~ocrow/python_string/

I use method 5. Didn't require many changes. There are some fancier methods in there, but they didn't appeal to me as much.

Comment: Given he's pinging an IP address 500 times I'm not sure faster IO is going to increase the overall speed much.

Comment: Appending is more expensive than using a buffer, due to every append causing allocation of new memory. If the list gets big enough, you could have some exciting things going on. Appending one line to a file that is 300MB will result in a copy of the old object with your new line on the end. (300 + 300 + line size) The difference in performance is not only in speed (order of magnitude), but also in terms of memory consumption.